# Bucketeer - Heroku's add-on s3 bucket configuration on Django

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, django-settings

I am currently using S3 to serve static files on Heroku. The S3 bucket was created and is managed by me and its settings.py file is the following.

```
import os

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = '<MY BUCKET NAME>'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

STATIC_URL = 'http://' + AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + '.s3.amazonaws.com/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'
```

Which is the same as this answer and it works perfectly fine: [Django + Heroku + S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766642/django-heroku-s3)

However I wanted to switch to Bucketeer which is a Heroku add-on that creates and manages a S3 bucket for you. But Bucketeer provides different parameters and the static URL looks different and I can't make it work. The URL has the following pattern: "bucketeer-heroku-shared.s3.amazonaws.com/UNIQUE_BUCKETEER_BUCKET_PREFIX/public/". So my updated code is the following.

```
#Bucketeer
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('BUCKETEER_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('BUCKETEER_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
BUCKETEER_BUCKET_PREFIX = os.environ.get('BUCKETEER_BUCKET_PREFIX')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
#Bucketeer Config
STATIC_URL = 'http://bucketeer-heroku-shared.s3.amazonaws.com/' +
             BUCKETEER_BUCKET_PREFIX + '/public/'
#I also tried
#STATIC_URL = 'http://bucketeer-heroku-shared.s3.amazonaws.com/' +
#             BUCKETEER_BUCKET_PREFIX + '/'
```

And this is the error I got.

```
Preparing static assets
Collectstatic configuration error. To debug, run:
$ heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

Needless to say no static files were present on the app, so when I ran the suggested command I got:

```
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
```

Which means I'm not authorized to access said bucket. Could somebody shed some light on what is going on here and how to fix it.

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't have an answer for you, but I'm curious - what are the advantages to using Bucketeer instead of an independently created S3 bucket?  Bucketeer seems much more expensive - cheapest is $5/month for 5GB of storage, whereas S3 on its own is $0.03/month per GB up to 1TB for standard storage.  Unless I'm not reading the docs correctly...

Comment: The only reason I use it is because I have to manage dozens of separate buckets for different parts of applications (and sometimes different applications). Heroku and Bucketeer manage AWS credentials for me so I don't have to keep up with credentials. I might change to a better-cheaper solution soon though.

Comment: Thank you - I really appreciate your taking the time to get back to me, even though I didn't have anything useful for you...