# Django REST + Heroku + Amazon S3 Bucket: How to configure?

Tags: python

I configured all to works locally, but if I change to save the media files into S3 bucket, images are dont saved into S3 Bucket :/

Comment: give us more info. Have you googled it before asking here?

Comment: its answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766642/django-heroku-s3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django + Heroku + S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766642/django-heroku-s3)