# Python script can't create folder on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

Having a script running on local debug server fine.

```
 if not os.path:
    os.mkdir(os.path.normpath(f'media/{request.user.id}/'))
 file_path = os.path.normpath(f'media/{request.user.id}/' + file_name + '.csv')
```

On Heroku I get an error. If I do not create directory "media" and do not deploy it to Heroku, I get error 'media/1/' doesn't exist.
What is wrong, why script can't create directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate issue is that your `if` condition is against the `os.path` module itself:

```py
if not os.path:
```

[`os.path` is part of the standard library](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) so `if os.path` should always be `True` as long as `os` or `os.path` has been imported. And if it ever *did* return `False` (e.g. if you have a broken or stripped down Python environment) you wouldn't be able to use it in the `if` block.

I suspect you want something more like this, using [`os.path.exists()`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists):

```py
user_media_folder = os.path.normpath(f'media/{request.user.id}/')

if not os.path.exists(user_media_folder):
    #         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    os.mkdir(user_media_folder)

file_path = os.path.normpath(user_media_folder + file_name + '.csv')
```

In any case, assuming you don't want those files to disappear you won't be able to use the local filesystem anyway. [It is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem): any change you make to it will be lost whenever your dyno restarts. This happens frequently (at least once per day) and unpredictably.

You'll have to store uploads somewhere else, e.g. [on Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) or Azure Blob Storage. See [Django + Heroku + S3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12766642/354577), for example.